# Unity - Matching Speed While Transistioning From Traveling on a Single Axis to Rotation Around a Circle

Tags: unity-game-engine, velocity, rigid-bodies

I am working on a simple project that consists of a ball with a rigid body being pushed along the x axis. The ball needs to transition 90 degrees and continue straight up.

I've created a box to serve as a pivot/rotation point and placed it exactly 5 units above the beginning of the 90 degree transition from and exactly 5 units away from the end of the transition. I've created two colliders that work as triggers; one at the beginning and one at the very end of the 90 degree transition.

So my ball will come zooming along on the x axis and hit the first trigger. When it does I reset the ball's velocity to zero and parent the ball to the box serving as a pivot/rotation point. I've then applied angular velocity to the box so that the ball will rotate exactly 5 units around the pivot point. When the ball hits the second collider at the end of the transition it is un-parented and velocity is reapplied so the ball can continue straight up.

So here is the question; if the ball is 5 units away from the pivot point, the distance traveled for the 90 degree transition would be something like : 5 * 2 = the circles diameter * PI = 31.4 units distance around the circle / 4 = 7.84 game units to travel for the entire 90 degree transition.

So how do I match the velocity the ball had while traveling solely on the x axis so that it has the same speed while transitioning using the pivot point rigid body's moveRotation function around a circular axis?

If I have a velocity vector of (-10, 0, 0) when I hit the first trigger how do I calculate what to feed into the moveRotation function so that a the ball, rotating 5 units away from the pivot point, is still traveling at 10 units a second?

Taking the original velocity (-10, 0, 0) and multiplying by the distance needed to travel for the 90 degree transition(7.85 units) looks really close but I can figure out how to check it.

Comment: The math is simple: "linear velocity = radius * angular velocity" - be careful if you use degrees for your angular velocity, you must convert to radians for this formula to work.

Comment: @JinJi : My math is fairly horrible; does your formula also mean angular velocity = linear velocity * radius? This was the formula I had guessed at and it looks close. When I hit the first trigger I have to calculate angular velocity and when I hit the second I would calculate linear velocity once again.

Comment: @Thanks JinJi, looks like it's working correctly.

Comment: if you have trouble with variables, you can always use numbers to get a better picture: "linear velocity = radius * angular velocity" is like: "8 = 2 * 4" and you know that "4 = 8 / 2" and therefore: "angular velocity = linear velocity / radius" - this will get you angular velocity in units: "radians per second". if you use "degrees per second" in your function you will have to multiply by (180/PI)

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again, your help was of great value, JinJi. :)